# not receiving correct output in html table with loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm beginning in learning PHP via a beginner's book, and am having difficulty on a particular exercise.  Here is the text of the exercise at the end of a chapter on decisions and looping:

> Write a script that counts from 1 to 10 in steps of 1. For each number, display whether that number is an odd or even number, and also display a message if the number is a prime number. Display this information within an HTML table.

I have searched www.php.net and looked for a similar issue on stackoverflow to what I'm having, but have not found anything to complete the code correctly.  Here is my code, followed by a description of the output it generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Counting to ten</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="common.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        th { text-align: center; background-color: #999; }
        th, td ( padding: 0.6em; )
        tr.alt td { background: #ddd }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Counting to ten</h3>

    <table cellspacing="1" border="1" style="width: 20em; border: 1px solid #999;">
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Odd/Even</th>
        </tr>

<?php

$count = 10;

$num1 = 0;
$num2 = 1;

for ( $i=2; $i <= $count; $i++ )

{
$sum = $num1 + $num2;
$num1 = $num2;
$num2 = $sum;
}

?>
    <tr <?php if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) echo ' class="alt"' ?>>
        <td><?php echo $i?></td>
        <td><?php echo "even" ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr <?php if ( $i % 2 == 1 ) ?>>
        <td><?php echo $i?></td>
        <td><?php echo "odd" ?></td>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not receiving an error.  I'm receiving output with a table, the proper headings and formatting, and two rows below saying "11, even" [onto next row] "11, odd".  I tried changing the value of $count to 0, which does not make sense in this exercise because I'm using "$i <= $count".  What about my code is not working to complete the table with the correct output?  Thank you for your kindness in reading.

Comment: I don't know how much you know so far, but this would be far easier if you just outputted $i, and found odd or even by using the `floor()` function.

Comment: @SableFoste can you show how you would use `floor()` to check for an even number?

Comment: @popnoodles, sorry you are right; I meant `ceil()`.  `$evenorodd =(ceil($i/2)==$i/2)?"even":"odd";`  Come to think of it... I guess you don't need either `floor()` or `ceil()` the statement should work without the calculation.

Comment: @SableFoste you *would* need `floor`, `ceil`, or `int` for that comparison. `$i%2?` is far fewer chars though. `$i&1?` works too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the part that outputs the table in the for loop...

```
<?php

$count = 10;

$num1 = 0;
$num2 = 1;

for ( $i=2; $i <= $count; $i++ ){
  $sum = $num1 + $num2;
  $num1 = $num2;
  $num2 = $sum;
  ?>
    <tr <?php if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) echo ' class="alt"' ?>>
        <td><?php echo $i?></td>
        <td><?php echo "even" ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr <?php if ( $i % 2 == 1 ) ?>>
        <td><?php echo $i?></td>
        <td><?php echo "odd" ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the html generation inside the loop **and** you only want to output one row per iteration

```
for ( $i=2; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
   ?>
    <tr <?php if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) echo ' class="alt"'; ?>>
        <td><?php echo $i?></td>
        <td><?php 
            if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) echo 'even';
            else echo 'odd'; # there's a shorter way to do this bit too
         ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Billy Moon and popnoodles.